# What are the beginning steps to show this/ solve this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The difference table for the sequence $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdots$ is

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sequence | $a_0$ | $a_1$ | $a_2$ | $a_3$ | $a_4$ | $a_5$ | $a_6$ | ... |
| first difference |  | $b_0$ | $b_1$ | $b_2$ | $b_3$ | $b_4$ | $b_5$ | ... |
| second difference |  |  | $c_0$ | $c_1$ | $c_2$ | $c_3$ | $c_4$ | ... |
| third difference |  |  |  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ... |

Show that
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &=& a_0\left( \begin{array}{r}n\\0\end{array} \right) + b_0\left( \begin{array}{r}n\\1\end{array} \right)+c_0\left( \begin{array}{r}n\\2\end{array} \right).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Use mathematical induction. It would be straightforward

Answer (score 1):

The fourth row says that for all $n\ge0$, $c_{n+1}-c_n=0$, so $c_n=c_0$ is a constant sequence.

Then $b_n$ is a linear sequence, with

$$c_n=b_{n+1}-b_n \implies b_{n+1}=b_n+c_0 \implies b_n=b_0+c_0n$$

and $a_n$ is a quadratic sequence, with

$$b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n \implies a_{n+1} = a_n+b_0+c_0n \implies a_n = a_0 + b_0n + c_0\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)$$

Now,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(n-k)=n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{n(n-1)}2=\binom n2$$

and of course $\binom n0=1$ and $\binom n1=n$.